# Change X Axis Scale for same data series chart

Tags: c#, .net

I have a specific place for chart area and specific scale to view data correctly , i do not wanna use Autoscale

What i want is ,.. if the Point > 'chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum'
Replot the point again with new X Axis scale. with changing the line color so i can identify its overscale

my first scale 0 --- 90
my over scale 90 ----180

As you see here [image]
i want to remove this point and plot it again with scale from 90 to 180 with red Line color and then complete my forward points normal

this is what i want to achieve [image]

this is my code i tried two different series but not work , i am missing something , i am reading data from csv file (nLines stands for lines number)

```
        for (int j = 0; j < nLines; j++)
        {

            chart.Series["Series0"].Points.AddXY(data[j, indX], data[j, indY]);


            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsReversed = true;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 90;
            chart.Series["Series0"].Color = Color.Blue;
            chart.Series["Series0"].BorderWidth = 2;




            List<DataPoint> lst = chart.Series["Series0"].Points.ToList<DataPoint>();





                if (lst[j].XValue > 90)
                {


                    chart.Series["Series15"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StepLine;
                    chart.Series["Series15"].Points.AddXY(data[j, indX], data[j, indY]);


                    chart.Series["Series15"].XAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
                    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.Minimum = 90;
                    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.Maximum = 180;
                    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
                    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
                    chart.Series["Series15"].Color = Color.Red;
                    chart.Series["Series15"].BorderWidth = 2;

                }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one way to do that, but the simplest uses a trick:

Since any **one** `Chartarea` can only display **one** scale and range of values we use **two** `Chartareas` and **overlay** them.

One has the normal range and the other the overflow range.

Now we add all data to two series: onece in the normal chartarea, and again in the overflow area..

Here is the result:

[image]

Here is how to prepare the `Chart`:

```
ChartArea ca1 = chart1.ChartAreas[0];

// the regular axis label interval and range
ca1.AxisX.Interval = 10;
ca1.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
ca1.AxisX.Maximum = 100;

// we add an extra chartarea
ChartArea ca2 = chart1.ChartAreas.Add("ca2");
// we align it..
ca2.AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.All;
ca2.AlignWithChartArea = ca1.Name;
// ..but we also need to set the position
// we create a hard coded element position that leaves room for labels and legend
ca1.Position = new ElementPosition(0, 0, 80, 90);  // 80% width
ca2.Position = new ElementPosition(0, 0, 80, 90);  // 90% height
// we make the overlayed area transparent
ca2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
// it needs a series to display the overflowing points
Series S22 = chart1.Series.Add("OverFlow");
S22.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StepLine;
S22.Color = Color.Red;
S22.ChartArea = "ca2";
```

The rest is basically just styling the axes.

```
// we want to show a secondary axis on top:
ca2.AxisX2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
// don't disable the primary axis if you want any labels!
// instead make its labels transparent!
ca2.AxisX.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;
// this is shared by the sec.axis event though it has its own property!
ca2.AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 10;
// I color the axis and the labels
ca2.AxisX2.LineColor = S22.Color;
ca2.AxisX2.LabelStyle.ForeColor = S22.Color;
// we need to set the range for both (!) axes:
ca2.AxisX2.Minimum = 100;
ca2.AxisX2.Maximum = 200;
ca2.AxisX.Minimum = 100;
ca2.AxisX.Maximum = 200;
```

Now you can add your values into both series unmodified.

I used ranges 0-100 and 100-200. Yours will work as well, of course. Also: If you need no `Legend` you can enlarge the width from 80% to 90% or more..

This is a lot easier than adding only the overflowing points to another series in the same chartarea because to look good that would also require to prevent gaps and false connections by adding tranparent extra points at just the right spots..

Comment: Thanks for help,.. woked for me,.. i guess for points overscale if i wanted to remove from blue line , i just check and remove them , but this will need to fill gaps everytime am i right??

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to remove a point. In my solution you add all points to both series. .In general: Removing points from a line type (line, spline, fastline, stepline) will create not gaps but, depending on the purpose, it will create wrong connections as now the neighbours of the point get connected. . So this is often not what one wants. Instead you can try to change the color of a point you want to disappear (and maybe the next one)   to `Color.Transparent`.

Comment: Thanks alot for help, yes you are right , i already tried to remove points and boom it fulls of wrong connections :D ,... i think Color.Transparent would have done better ,... thanks again for help